# Any way to get git diff with commit changes in single command

Tags: git

Is there any way we can get the details of diff of a file along with it's commit ID details through a single command ? Currently , "git diff tag1..tag2" gives me the entire code change between the two tags but not the commit ID and reasons for commit . When i use " git log " it gives me complete commit change with changes that i'm not concerned with when comparing two tags .

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? What do you mean by "details of diff of a file along with it's commit ID"?

Comment: sure .. For E.g git diff command gives me something like 
diff --git a/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp b/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp
index 662a1fa..64f9766 100644
--- a/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp
+++ b/opengl/libagl/egl.cpp
followed by the exact code change( added / subtracted) .

but this change also has a commit ID and commit reason which i want in the same diff file. So the idea is that if i'm seeing a change , i can also see the reason for it . Such details are possible to get via "git log " but running "git log tag1..tag2 " is giving me whole different result with files that are not part of git diff

Comment: You want commit messages, commit hashes and entire diffs between two points in your commit tree?

Answer (score 24):

> but this change also has a commit ID and commit reason which i want in
>   the same diff file

I think there is a little confusion here. The git-diff outputs the difference between one commit and another, that difference is not just one commit, it represents a series of commits in the range you specify (662a1fa..64f9766 in the example you gave). So that would be multiple commit IDs and messages, perhaps even thousands if your tags are far enough apart.

If git diff were to output all the associated commit messages you would have no good way of telling which part of the diff is associated with each commit ID and commit message. This is why git log exists.

Git log does display each commit one after another in the range you specify and so that's why it will display commit messages.

git-diff shows you the difference between a and z.
git-log shows you the journey a took to become z.

With that in mind, I'm guessing this is probably what you are looking for:

`git log --color -p --full-diff tag1..tag2`